# Perl DBI Error when 3 concurrent scripts write to a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a script on an AWS EC2 instance that inserts a bunch of rows into an InnoDB table in a MySQL db on another EC2 instance. If I run the script, all works fine and the script terminates as expected. If I kick off the scripts 3 times in succession so that there are three processes spawned, all the scripts die simultaneously after having inserted a few thousand rows each. Why?

Keep in mind:

1. Each script has unique DBH and STH handles so there shouldn't be a connection collision
2. The max_connections setting on MySQL is set to 150
3. Nothing the MySQL error logs
4. I've verified that connections are open and closed immediately
5. There are no nested db calls inside a while($sta->fetch()) loop
6. I'm logged into the mysql shell and MySQL seems to be operating normally immediately prior to and after DBI throws the error

Here's the error:

```
DBI connect('database:45.218.216.31:3306','root',...) failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '45.218.216.31' (99) at /home/ubuntu/perl/modules/custom.pm line 256
```

Can't connect to MySQL server on '45.218.216.31' (99)Connection failed at /home/ubuntu/perl/modules/custom.pm line 256.

Line 256 is your normal connection method:

```
my $dbh411a = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user_name, $db_password) or die $DBI::errstr, "Connection failed";
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated - thank you.

UPDATE--------

Thanks to everybody that commented, they were very helpful. I was able to fix the script by following @jordanm's suggestion about keeping the db connection open for the duration of the script. Originally, we were opening and closing connections per insert which was generating MySQL connection requests faster than connections were being closed until it maxed out and refused any new connections.

Comment: you may be out of local outgoing ports?

Comment: Why are not keeping the connection open for the duration of the script?

Comment: Are you watching the process list `SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST` or a util like innotop while this happens? Are you sure you are not running into a metadata locking issue and the inserts are then piling up and you hit max connections(threads) and your script bombs out? Are you using START TRANSACTION/COMMIT for ea. insert? Or just autocommit?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing in your scripts. You say that they bomb "after having inserted a few thousand rows each". Then you tell us that "There are no nested db calls inside a while($sta->fetch()) loop". So are you inserting for selecting? Do you connect one or after each insert/select?

Comment: @jordanm - please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thx!